# Show thumbnail in post wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How use corect function for show thumbnail in post?

And how insert `'order' => 'asc'`?

My actual code:

```
function show_thumb() {
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_id );
}
```

and

```
<?php echo show_thumb(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has built in functions for this

inside the loop you can use

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
```

[Codex Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

and outside of the loop

```
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

[Codex Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: What does this mean "inside the loop"?... I'm a beginner and it's hard to understand.

Comment: that's a whole another question...the gist of it is - the loop iterates over multiple posts on the same page and inside this loop there are certain functions that are available....check [this out](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wordpress-loop-beginners-guide) for more info

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in a loop showing posts...

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
     the_post_thumbnail();
}
```